# Almost a partial order, is a partial order induced anyway?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

If I have a set $S$ and a relation $\rho$ on $S$, such that $\rho$ is reflexive and antisymmetric, and I draw the arrow diagram of this, and this diagram is connected, with no cycles, is transitivity induced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always find the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of any such relation by drawing a link between $A$ and $B$ if there is a path from $A$ to $B$.  If the original graph contains no cycles (ignoring the reflexive ones), then its transitive closure will contain no cycles either, and it will still be anti-symmetric.  It will also still be reflexive of course and, since it is the transitive closure, transitive. Thus, the transitive closure of such a relation will indeed be a partial order.